Joining two data frames to replace values in one with another
I have two data frames that look like these:
df1 <- data.frame("Year" = c(1991, 1997, 2002, 2009, 2016, 2024), 
              "Name" = c("Amy", "Ben", "Chad", "Dan", "Emily", "Frank"), 
              "Gender" = c("F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M"))
df2 <- data.frame("Year" = c(1997, 1997, 1997, 2009, 2009, 2016, 2016), 
              "Name" = c("Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Dan", "Dan", "Emily", "Emily"), 
              "Gender" = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F"), 
              "Year_new" = c(1998, 2002, 2004, 2009, 2010, 2017, 2020), 
              "Name_new" = c("Bella", "Brandon", "Brittany", "David", "Dylan", "Emma", "Ethan"), 
              "Gender_new" = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M"))

I want to merge df1 and df2 to replace Year, Name and Gender that overlap between df1 and df2 into Year_new, Name_new and Gender_new, so that the result will look like this:
df3 <- data.frame("Year" = c(1991, 1998, 2002, 2004, 2002, 2009, 2010, 2017, 2020, 2024), 
              "Name" = c("Amy", "Bella", "Brandon", "Brittany", "Chad", "David", "Dylan", "Emma", "Ethan", "Frank"), 
              "Gender" = c("F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M"))

I tried doing this by using full_join, coalesce and rename like below.
df3 <- full_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  mutate("Year_new" = coalesce(Year, Year_new), 
             "Name_new" = coalesce(Name, Name_new), 
             "Gender_new" = coalesce(Gender, Gender_new)) %>% 
  select(Year_new:Gender_new) %>% 
  rename(Year = Year_new, Name = Name_new, Gender = Gender_new)

But this way, coalesce is overwriting the values I'd like to keep from df2. I also feel like this might not be the easiest/most efficient way. Is there a function other than full_join or coalesce that would work in this case?

You have the arguments in coalesce() backwards.  Reverse them and you'll get your desired result - you also don't need the select and rename steps, just overwrite the three variables and use the .keep argument e.g mutate(Year = coalesce(Year_new, Year), .keep = "unused"). As for another way, you could use rows_update() but you'd need to create a common key in both datasets.

Bind what's only in df1 with what's new in df2 (properly renamed):
library(dplyr)

# You don't really need this "column-selection" helper but..
aux_cols <- c("Year", "Name", "Gender")

# Bind what's only in `df1`..
# ..with what´s "new" in `df2` (renamed withou "_new) 
new_df <- bind_rows(
  anti_join(df1, df2, by = aux_cols),

  transmute(
    semi_join(df2, df1, by = aux_cols),
    across(ends_with("_new"), .names = "{str_remove({.col}, '_new')}")))

The output:
# `arrange` the output by `Year and `Name` 
> arrange(new_df, Year, Name)
   Year     Name Gender
1  1991      Amy      F
2  1998    Bella      F
3  2002  Brandon      M
4  2002     Chad      M
5  2004 Brittany      F
6  2009    David      M
7  2010    Dylan      M
8  2017     Emma      F
9  2020    Ethan      M
10 2024    Frank      M

Edit. If you're not into tidyverse that much, you can try this:
aux_cols <- c("Year", "Name", "Gender")

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)

aux_rows <- complete.cases(df3)
aux_cols <- c("Year", "Name", "Gender")

df3[aux_rows, aux_cols] <- df3[aux_rows, paste0(aux_cols, "_new")]
df3 <- df3[do.call(order, df3[aux_cols]), aux_cols]

The output:
> df3
   Year     Name Gender
1  1991      Amy      F
2  1998    Bella      F
3  2002  Brandon      M
5  2002     Chad      M
4  2004 Brittany      F
6  2009    David      M
7  2010    Dylan      M
8  2017     Emma      F
9  2020    Ethan      M
10 2024    Frank      M

